# UCB: where is delta and standard deviation?

Tags: multiarmed-bandit

One of the most popular multi-armed bandit is the **Upper Confidence Bound (UCB)** line of algorithms (see references below).

My understanding is that we try to find the largest plausible estimate of the mean of arm $i$: $$\hat\mu_i(t-1) + \sqrt{\frac{2\sigma}{n_i(t-1)}\log\frac{1}{\delta}},$$
where $\hat\mu_i(t)$ is the average reward of arm $i$ until time $t$ and $n_i(t)$ is the number of times arm $i$ has been chosen.

The second term of the formula is the confidence tail. We assume that rewards are $\sigma^2$-subgaussian which (by definition) means we have the upper-bound $\text P(\hat\mu\geq\varepsilon)\leq\exp(-\frac{n\varepsilon^2}{2\sigma})$. By setting $\delta=\exp(-\frac{n\varepsilon^2}{2\sigma})$, we have that $\text P(\hat\mu\geq\sqrt{\frac{2\sigma}{n}\log\frac{1}{\delta}}) \leq \delta$.

In graphical terms, I believe (at each iteration) we want to find the arm that maximizes:

[image: The largest plausible estimate of the mean of the arm]

My question is two-fold:

1. Isn't this sensitive to the magnitude of the mean and deviation? What if I don't know the deviation $\sigma$ of my rewards? Most authors seem to assume $\sigma=1$, but this just seems wrong. In my particular case, UCB gives bad results because of this (I think). Should I just try different values instead of $\sigma$? Should I try somehow to estimate it? Likewise, I am not completely sure if my $\mu=0$ -- is this a problem?
2. Why do so many people replace $\frac{1}{\sigma}$ by something like $1/\delta=f(t)=1+t\log^2(t)$? I could not find this from the original paper (which I found hard to read) or any of the references.

I guess my question is: why do I see so many implementations like this?

```
formula = mu + np.sqrt(2*np.log(it)/n)
```

Why do $\sigma$ and $\delta$ disappear?

References:

1. [A Survey of Online Experiment Design with the Stochastic Multi-Armed Bandit](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00757) (2015)
2. [Bandit Algorithms blog](http://banditalgs.com/)

Comment: regarding the $\mu=0$ - the point of MAB task is to find the action with highest $\mu$, so you are not assuming the value of $\mu$. (If you would know /assume the true value of $\mu$, you would just select the action with highest $\mu$).

Answer (score 1):

1) It shouldn't necessarily be sensitive to the mean, but it will definitely be sensitive to the variance. Most authors do assume the reward distribution (or rather, the noise $X - \mathbb{E}[X]$) is 1-subgaussian, mostly for convenience. You'll need to adjust the algorithm if you believe your variance is higher than 1. See the UCB-Tuned algorithm on page 15 of your first reference. It shouldn't matter if your $\mu \neq 0$. If the means of all the reward distributions had to be 0, then bandits would be a useless construction.

2) The specific $1/\delta$ you mention is the constant that is asymptotically optimal. See chapter 8 of http://downloads.tor-lattimore.com/banditbook/book.pdf

To answer your last question: Tthe $\sigma$ disappears likely due to assuming $\sigma=1$. The $\delta$ disappears because you need to make some choice for $\delta$, in this case it looks like that would be part of the "it" expression.